# Animation ignored in Android 4.2

Tags: android

I have an `ExpandAnimation` for my list view items:

```
public class ExpandAnimation extends Animation {
    private AnimationCompletedCallback callback = null;
    private View viewToAnimate = null;
    private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams viewToAnimateLayoutParams = null;
    private int marginStart = 0;
    private int marginEnd = 0;
    private boolean isVisibleAfter = false;
    private boolean isEndedAlready = false;

    public ExpandAnimation(AnimationCompletedCallback callback, View view, int duration) {
        this.setDuration(duration);

        this.callback = callback;

        this.viewToAnimate = view;
        this.viewToAnimateLayoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();

        this.isVisibleAfter = (view.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE);

        this.marginStart = this.viewToAnimateLayoutParams.bottomMargin;
        this.marginEnd = (this.marginStart == 0 ? (0 - view.getHeight()) : 0);

        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation transformation) {
        super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, transformation);

        if (interpolatedTime < 1.0f) {
            this.viewToAnimateLayoutParams.bottomMargin = this.marginStart + (int) ((this.marginEnd - this.marginStart) * interpolatedTime);
            this.viewToAnimate.requestLayout();
        } else if (!this.isEndedAlready) {
            this.viewToAnimateLayoutParams.bottomMargin = this.marginEnd;
            this.viewToAnimate.requestLayout();

            if (this.isVisibleAfter) {
                this.viewToAnimate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            this.isEndedAlready = true;

            this.callback.onAnimationCompleted();
        }
    }
}
```

Thi Animation works on Android 4.4+ But on Android 4.2 for example then animation just gets skipped. When i set the duration to `500` for example i see nothing for 500 ms and than the view collapse instantly same when i open it. nothing happens for 500ms and than the view expands instantly. that means all the steps between 0 and 500 ms arent showing at all.

Why?

Comment: Maybe you're utilising something that requires a later version of Android. Have you checked it is only 4.2 that doesn't work or does 4.0 not work either?

Comment: 4.0 also does not work but i dont get any api warnings because my min sdk is set to 4.2 and normally when i use something requireing 4.4 as minimum sdk i get warnings or errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange. I was working with a `RelativeLayout` i switched to `LinearLayout` now and the animation works now.